# How can I install libicui18n.so.52 on travis?

Tags: travis-ci

How can I install libicui18n.so.52 on travis ?

I have a problem with libicui18n.so.52

```
[phantomjs.launcher]: /home/travis/build/MyProject/node_modules/karma-phantomjs2-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs2-ext/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.52: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried this in my .travis.yml :

```
sudo: false

before_install:
  - apt-get install -i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
```

But I have this error :

```
The command "sudo apt-get install -y libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb" failed and exited with 100 during .
```

Comment: Can you try installing *just* `libicu52`?

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question. Place an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I resolved my problem this morning with this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222589/install-package-on-travis-ci-with-sudofalse , I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this :

```
sudo: required

before_install:
  - sudo wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
  - sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
```