# Install package on Travis-ci with sudo:false

Tags: docker, travis-ci

How can I Iinstall a package on Travis-ci with sudo:false in travis.yml ?

I have my travis.yml :

```
sudo: false

install:
  - wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
  - sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
```

I have an error :

> sudo: must be setuid root
>
> The command "sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb" failed and exited with 1 during .

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, at least some.

Travis has a [whitelist of allowed packages](https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist) you can install from using the containerised environment. Instead of using wget and dpkg, or apt, you define the packages in your yaml under the `addons` section. Check https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/.

In the yaml you'd have something like:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - ncftp
```

`ncftp` is whitelisted [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist/blob/master/ubuntu-precise#L8946).

If you need packages which are not whitelisted, you can set `sudo: true` and your build will be launched in a non-containerised environment, so you have root (`sudo`) access to install whatever you want. Alternatively you can raise an issue on their Github to add a whitelist for your package.